# Make GoogleMap holds its position while using MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using MMDrawerController and GoogleMap's api in my project.
I want to have a GoogleMap's view with two left and right slide-out navigation bars, and they only appears when I swipe within 20px from left and right respectively.
Everything works as expected, except:
When I swipe on the benzel, which is 20px, of mapView with property:

```
[drawerController
setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeBezelPanningCenterView];
```

it also makes the googlemap's View responds to the pan gesture too, and makes it swipes away.

The close gesture

```
[drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
```

works fine with

```
[drawerController 
setCenterHiddenInteractionMode:MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionModeNone];
```

How can I make the map stays still when sliding out the drawers ?

Thank you !

**----------------**

**Answer**: **(stackoverflow doesn't let me answer my question because it was posted less than 8 hours ago)**

I've found the solution. Credit goes to https://github.com/kcharwood. I just modify some of his code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view = _mapView;

    [[self.view.subviews[0] gestureRecognizers] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIGestureRecognizer * gesture, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        [gesture setDelegate:self];
    }];
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect boundingRect = self.view.bounds;
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]){
        boundingRect.origin.x+=20;
        boundingRect.size.width-=40;
    }
    return CGRectContainsPoint(boundingRect, location);
}


-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

Note: adhere  so `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`  will available.

20 and 40 mean the left and right area of the view. If the pan gestures starting location within these areas, the map won't move.
If you want only left: change them to 20 and 20.
If you want them smaller, like 10 and 20, remember to change `CGFloat const MMDrawerBezelRange = 20.0f;` (default value) in MMDrawerController.m to 10.

Answer (score 3):

I found a more elegant solution by simply tying together the UIGestureRecognizers so that the drawer's pan gesture supersedes the map's pan gesture:

```
// walk the drawer controller's gesture recognizers
UIGestureRecognizer *drawerPanGestureRecognizer = nil;
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in drawerController.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    // grab the pan gesture recognizer
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        drawerPanGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer;
        break;
    }
}

// walk the map view's gesture recognizers
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in ((UIView *)mapView.subviews[0]).gestureRecognizers) {
    // to find the pan gesture recognizer
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        // panning the drawer should prevent panning the map view
        [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:drawerPanGestureRecognizer];
        break;
    }
}
```